# Position of divs with big space for laying out photos

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the problem with my layouts, made in CSS. No Javascript used because I don't know how to position divs (posts) dynamically. Divs have spaces and lines where I don't want those lines because of different sizes of divs.

Look at these photo please;

- http://postimage.org/image/hibb48iq3/
- http://postimage.org/image/6h9b8mpt9/

I don't want that specified big space. I am trying to use various properties of display in the CSS but nothing changes that big space. My CSS code is this:

```
#post {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    background: #fbffff;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: tahoma;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
```

If someone have some solution by using CSS or Javascript, that would be helpful.  My code is in Ruby on Rails.

I make a sample in JS fiddle to solve: http://jsfiddle.net/DLKP6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a **dynamic grid layout** - [here you can find a repository of solutions](http://www.queness.com/post/11133/the-famous-pinterest-dynamic-grid-layout-and-design-inspirations).

As already stated I advise you to check [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), and [Wookmark plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript to achieve that,
there are many [Pinterest like Dynamic Grid Layouts](http://www.wtfdiary.com/2012/08/6-amazing-jquery-plugins-to-design.html) that could help you, here below is the famous one.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

and here is this superb article that can help you setting it up.

[Responsive jQuery Masonry](http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout)